# Index of Boost cmake components

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I am using boost quite often, but every time I try to use it I have doubts about what is the name of Boost module, which I should add in cmake.

For example in my last project I wanted to use `boost::concurrent::sync_queue` and I can't find anywhere what is the name of the module. I finally found it by accident, by locating random github project that already using it, so I just look into `CMakeLists.txt`.

At the end I got that line:
`find_package(Boost 1.70 REQUIRED COMPONENTS thread )`
But first i've tried:

```
find_package(Boost 1.70 REQUIRED COMPONENTS concurrent )
find_package(Boost 1.70 REQUIRED COMPONENTS threading )
find_package(Boost 1.70 REQUIRED COMPONENTS threads )
```

And as I remember in all of my project this is one of most frustrating phase of cmake.
I found [this site](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/module/FindBoost.html) but there is only avaiable flags/options in cmake.

Do any of you have set/list/index or tip how to link used class/functionallity from boost to required component?
If such index has relation to boost version it would be priceless and really handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `CMake\share\cmake-3.*\Modules\FindBoost.cmake`:

```
FindBoost
---------

Find Boost include dirs and libraries

Use this module by invoking find_package with the form::

  find_package(Boost
    [version] [EXACT]      # Minimum or EXACT version e.g. 1.67.0
    [REQUIRED]             # Fail with error if Boost is not found
    [COMPONENTS <libs>...] # Boost libraries by their canonical name
                           # e.g. "date_time" for "libboost_date_time"
    [OPTIONAL_COMPONENTS <libs>...]
                           # Optional Boost libraries by their canonical name)
    )                      # e.g. "date_time" for "libboost_date_time"
```

It says to use:

> Boost libraries by their canonical name e.g. "date_time" for "libboost_date_time"

Comment: Ok, so i searched this file (`/usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindBoost.cmake` on Ubuntu 20.04) and after some regexing stuff i got theese modules:
`['random', 'math_c99f', 'regex', 'mpi', 'chrono', 'context', 'math_tr1f', 'thread', 'math_tr1', 'log_setup', 'atomic', 'math_c99', 'math_c99l', 'date_time', 'system', 'filesystem', 'fiber', 'serialization', 'math_tr1l']`, but for me it doesn't look like all avaiable modules, maybe i did it bad. If it would be helpful i extract it from lines 850~1160

Comment: sorry, i did it for nothing, but canonical name is 2'nd part of include directive path?
for `#include <boost/thread/sync_queue>` it's `thread`?